# playback of ffmpeg converted video on LDPI device (Samsung S5300 240 x 320)

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have Full HD video taken by Samsung Galaxy S4 camera.
video stream info as follows:

```
{"index":0,"codec_name":"h264","codec_long_name":"H.264 \/ AVC \/ MPEG-4 AVC \/ MPEG-4 part 10","profile":"High","codec_type":"video","codec_time_base":"1\/180000","codec_tag_string":"avc1","codec_tag":"0x31637661","width":1920,"height":1080,"has_b_frames":0,"sample_aspect_ratio":"0:1","display_aspect_ratio":"0:1","pix_fmt":"yuv420p","level":40,"r_frame_rate":"30\/1","avg_frame_rate":"21240000\/707831","time_base":"1\/90000","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":1415662,"duration":"15.729578","bit_rate":"16553536","nb_frames":"472","disposition":{"default":1,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0},"tags":{"rotate":"90","creation_time":"2013-12-24 10:19:18","language":"eng","handler_name":"VideoHandle"}}
```

in short it is 1920x1080, 16KK bitrate, rotation: 90.
I'm converting it using ffmpeg by the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 8 -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -s 324x576 -strict -2 -b:v 512k -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 16000 -ab 32000 -vf "transpose=1" -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0  output.mp4
```

The output video stream info:

```
 {"index":0,"codec_name":"h264","codec_long_name":"H.264 \/ AVC \/ MPEG-4 AVC \/ MPEG-4 part 10","profile":"Constrained Baseline","codec_type":"video","codec_time_base":"1\/48","codec_tag_string":"avc1","codec_tag":"0x31637661","width":324,"height":576,"has_b_frames":0,"sample_aspect_ratio":"0:1","display_aspect_ratio":"0:1","pix_fmt":"yuv420p","level":30,"r_frame_rate":"24\/1","avg_frame_rate":"24\/1","time_base":"1\/12288","start_pts":0,"start_time":"0.000000","duration_ts":72192,"duration":"5.875000","bit_rate":"521597","nb_frames":"141","disposition":{"default":1,"dub":0,"original":0,"comment":0,"lyrics":0,"karaoke":0,"forced":0,"hearing_impaired":0,"visual_impaired":0,"clean_effects":0,"attached_pic":0},"tags":{"language":"eng","handler_name":"VideoHandler"}}
```

The output video being played without any problem, on many different devices and OSes including different iOs and androids, but Samsung S5300 doesn't play it. From the device log I can see the following exception:

```
E/AwesomePlayer( 1349): This resolution [324X576] Not Supported
```

But, when I change the width and height to 576x324 the video can be played on S5300, but in wrong rotation.
What should I add in ffmpeg parameters to make it play in correct orientation?

ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-12-22-911676c Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on Dec 22 2013 22:55:31 with gcc 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add black margins to get the target resolution.

for example

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf pad="704:576:(704-324)/2:0" out.mp4`

(for more information about `pad` filter see http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad)